# Basic Quantum mechanics: This nonphysical "fun" homework with operators just gives me nonsense

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, born-rule

For QM homework we are given $\vert \psi \rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^3 c_i \vert i \rangle$ where $\vert i \rangle$ represent different positions. Firstly we are asked $P(i=2\vert \psi)$ which is given $P(i=2\vert \psi ) = \vert \langle 2 \vert \psi \rangle \vert ^2$ by definition of probability amplitudes. Secondly we are given an operator $\hat{V}$, find its eigenstates $\vert V_1\rangle, \vert V_2\rangle, \vert V_3\rangle$ whose eigenvalues happen to be $-2, 0, 2$, where $\vert V_i \rangle$ represent some quality of the object. We are then asked to find the probability of getting attribute $\vert V_2\rangle $ given the initial state $\vert \psi \rangle$, that is $P(V_2 \vert \psi)$. Here I am complety lost, initialy I thought the way to get this was $P(V_2 \vert \psi) = \vert \langle V_2\vert \hat{V} \vert \psi \rangle \vert^2$ since a given observable is "linked" to its operator (at least for expected values of continous variables), this however must be nonsense (?) since this means $P(V_2\vert V_2) = 0$ since $V_2$ is an eigenstate with eigenvalue 0 this always gives zero, which makes no sense. So I tested using $P(V_2 \vert \psi) = \vert 
 \langle V_2\vert \psi \rangle \vert^2$ which doesn't give those nonsense answers, however it just feels wrong, for example it means $P(V_2 \vert \psi) = P(\psi \vert V_2)$ which doesn't make any sense either. What is the right approach? I guess my professor wants me to understand that quantum is weird but that makes it hard to know if I'm wrong or not.

Comment: Why "it means P(V2|ψ)=P(ψ|V2) which doesn't make any sense either"? I mean it is true: this probabilities are equal, but why it "does not make any sense"?

Answer (score 3):

Measurement (in the simplest case of projective measurements of observables whose operators display no degeneracy) goes like this.  Given a state $\lvert \psi \rangle$ and a Hermitian operator $\hat{V}$, the probability of getting the outcome $v_j$ (an eigenvalue of $\hat{V}$) upon measuring the observable associated with $\hat{V}$ is equal to
$$
P(v_j | \lvert\psi\rangle) = \lvert \langle v_j | \psi \rangle\rvert^2\,,
$$
where $\hat{V}\lvert v_j\rangle = v_j \lvert v_j\rangle$, i.e., $\lvert v_j\rangle$ is the eigenvector of $\hat{V}$ corresponding to eigenvalue $v_j$.

In other words, if you expand the state in the eigenbasis of $\hat{V}$, i.e.,
$$
\lvert \psi \rangle = \sum_j c_j \lvert v_j \rangle\,,
$$
then the probability of getting $v_j$ upon measuring $\hat{V}$ is $\lvert c_j \rvert^2$, and of course $c_j = \langle v_j | \psi \rangle$.

Now, you wonder about the "equality"
$$P(V_2 | \psi) = P( \psi | V_2)\,.$$
In my opinion, you are committing a category error by even writing this down. Note that above, I have explicitly made the second entry of the conditional probability a *vector* whereas the first entry is a *number*. In quantum mechanics, we compute the probabilities of the *outcomes* of experiments, conditional on the state of the system at the time of measurement.  Outcomes of experiments are real numbers, e.g., the eigenvalues of an operator representing a physical observable. So, while, we can interpret
$
P(v_2 | |\psi\rangle)
$
as the probability of getting the outcome $v_2$ upon measuring $\hat{V}$ given the state of the system is $\lvert \psi \rangle$, we can't interpret
$
P(\lvert \psi\rangle | v_2)
$
at all, because $|\psi\rangle$ is not a measurement outcome, and $v_2$ is not a state. Now, we could rescue this by saying that $|\psi\rangle$ might be an eigenvector of some other operator $\hat{Q}$ with eigenvalue $a_{\psi}$, and so, supposing again that $\hat{Q}$ is non-degenerate, then we can write
$
P(a_{\psi} | |v_2\rangle)
$
as the probability of getting $a_{\psi}$ as the outcome of the measurement of $\hat{Q}$ given the state of the system is $|v_2\rangle$, and indeed, this really is the same as $
P(v_2 | |\psi\rangle)
$,
because the expansion of a vector in an orthonormal basis in terms of the vectors in *another* orthonormal basis has this reciprocity.

---

(Always debunk the myth and/or present the misconception *after* the explanation of what is true, so:)

There is a common misconception among students first learning quantum mechanics that the *mathematical* action of an operator on a state is somehow linked to the *physical* act of measuring that operator given the system is in that state.  It's just the case that $\hat{V}\lvert \psi\rangle$ doesn't correspond to any sort of measurement.